# How to use proxy authentication with xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml, proxy, xsd, dtd

I'm trying to use xsd.exe to create a c# class. In particular I'm trying to use http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/capabilities_1_1_1.xml to generate the xsd to then generate the class. I managed to get a class from the 1.3.0 version of the specification via xsd.exe in windows command line but when I try to do the same for this version I get a proxy authentication error like below.

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error when I didn't for the other translation? Also if it really is my proxy blocking xsd then how do I tell xsd to use my credentials for http requests?

![Proxy error image][2]

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks for your time in advance

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIbHM.jpg
```

EDIT: The image doesn't seem to be working for me so I'll just write the error message -

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin>xsd.exe capabilities_1_1_1.xml

Microsoft (R) XML Schemas/Datatypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Error: There was an error processing 'capabilities_1_1_1.xml".
  - The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this one I figured out that the WMS.xml provided by the OGC does NOT have all it's namespaces working correctly. In particular one of the URL references (http://www.digitalearth.gov/wmt/xml/capabilities_1_1_1.dtd) does NOT exist anymore which was confusing my network hence returning a 407 proxy authentication required error.

THE SOLUTION:

Change the DTD referenced in OGCs capabilities.xml file to point to the DTD on their website. Why it doesn't already point to that by default I DO NOT KNOW. digitalearth.gov looks like it's been down since 2006 so it's very old. Anyway once the reference for the DTD was changed I was able to create the XSD and c# class with ease.